# passport session authentication works on postman but it breaks in client (Node Js & React Js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js, mongostore

I'm trying to login with passport session exrpess and mongodb, the problem is that it's not working on the client side **(my session is created correctly even from the client, but when I have to enter a protected route the req.user returns undefined)** I'm using axios to handle the requests to the server, as it says in the title, **when I try it with postman to the same routes that I have on the client it works perfect**...

**The server responds with the else of this function (located in passport.js): **

```
const checkAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("REQUEST USER", req.user)
    console.log("BREAK HERE ", req.isAuthenticated())
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){ 
        console.log("DSADASDASDAS ", req.isAuthenticated())
        return next() 
    }else{
        // res.status(302).redirect("http://localhost:3000/login")
        res.status(302).json({message: "??????"})    
    }
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with the deserialize or the way I handle requests on the client side, if you can help me I would appreciate it

**CLIENT SIDE: login.jsx**

```
async function handleVerify(e){
    try {
      e.preventDefault()
      const query = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/user/login", {
        username: formValue.username,
        password: formValue.password
      });
      console.log(query)

      if(query.status === 302 || 200){
        console.log("Login successfull")     //last thing on console 
        const queryPost = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/post/home", {    //Breaks Here
          withCredentials: true 
        })     
        console.log("DSADSADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", queryPost)
        if(queryPost.status === 200){
          navigate("/")
        }

      }else{
        setFormValue({
          username: "",
          password: ""
        })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("HANDLE VERIFY ERROR ", error)

    }  
  }
```

**PASSPORT: passport.js**

```
const passport = require("passport")
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy

const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const secretKey = "123"

const controller = require("../controllers/userController")


passport.use("auth", new LocalStrategy(
    async (username, password, done) => {
        try {
            const result = await controller.auth(username, password)  
            
            console.log("PASSPORT USER: ", result)
            if(result.status === 200){
                const serializedUser = {email: result.user[0].email}

                const payload = {
                    username: result.user[0].username,
                    email: result.user[0].email
                
                }
                const token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, {expiresIn: "1h" })
                console.log("token  ", token)

            
                // localStorage.setItem("token", token)

                return done(null, serializedUser, token)
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {message: "Usuario no encontrado"})
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("PASSPORT AUTH ERROR ", error)
            return done(null, error)
        }
    }
)) 


passport.serializeUser((user, done) =>{
    console.log("SERIALIZED", user)
    done(null, user.email)

})



passport.deserializeUser(async (email, done) =>{
    try {
        // const completeUser = await controller.getByEmail(email)
        console.log("DESERIALIZED", email)
        done(null, email)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("DESERIALIZE ERROR ", error)
        done(error)
    }
})




const checkAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("REQUEST USER", req.user)
    console.log("BREAK HERE ", req.isAuthenticated())
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){ 
        console.log("DSADASDASDAS ", req.isAuthenticated())
        return next() 
    }else{
        // res.status(302).redirect("http://localhost:3000/login")
        res.status(302).json({message: "??????"})    
    }
}



const checkToken = (req, res, next) =>{
    const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1]
    console.log("middle TOKEN ", token)
        if(!token){
            return res.status(401).json({message: "Token no proporcionada"})
        }
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secretKey)
        req.user = decoded
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(403).json(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    checkToken,
    checkAuthenticated,
    passport
}
```

**SERVER INDEX: server.jS**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express")
const passport = require("passport")
const session = require("express-session")
const http = require("http")
const cors = require("cors")

const {checkToken, checkAuthenticated} = require("./security/passport")
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")
const sessionOpts = {
    secret: "shhh",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: "MONGOURL",            
        dbName: "test",
        collectionName: "sessions"
    })
}


const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
}))

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(session(sessionOpts))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



const { router: userRouter } = require("./routers/api/user");
const { router: postRouter } = require("./routers/api/posts");
const interactionsRouter = require("./routers/api/interactions")



app.use("/api/user", userRouter)
app.use("/api/post", checkAuthenticated, postRouter)    
app.use("/api/interactions", checkToken, interactionsRouter)




const server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(PORT, () => {

    console.log("Server running")

})



server.on("error", () => {

    console.log("Something failed", "error")

})
```

**POST ROUTES:  post.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const {Router} = express;
const router = Router();

const PostModel = require("../../models/post");
const controller = new PostModel


router.get("/home", controller.getAll)

router.post("/home/post", controller.post)


module.exports = {
    router,
    controller
}
```

**USER ROUTES: user.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const {Router} = express;
const router = Router();


const controller = require("../../controllers/userController")

const {passport} = require("../../security/passport");
const {checkAuthenticated} = require("../../security/passport")


router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("auth"),controller.verify)

router.post("/login/r", passport.authenticate("auth"), controller.register)

router.get("/logout", controller.logout)


module.exports = {
    router,
    controller
}
```

The flow goes until the serialization and creation of the session, then it doesn't work, I saw many similar problems but the answers of these did not help me